# Rails query on different models in a multi-level association chain

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have a multi-level model structure, and I am trying to create a query where I can search for either an attribute on the main parent model, or the last model in the associatioon change. My structure looks like the following:

```
class Parent
    attr_accessible :pname
    has_one :child
end

class Child
    has_many :infos
end

class Info
    has_one :setting
end

class Setting
    has_many :subsettings
end

class Subsetting
    attr_accessible :sname
end
```

What I am trying to do is create a where query, where i can pull all parents where either the "pname = X" or "sname = X". However, I am unsure of how to create the associations that deep: Is there a way I can do it cleanly using active record, or is it better to create a mysql query directly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm typing this freehand, so it's possible this won't be 100%, but you should be able to do something like the following...

```
class Parent
  has_one :child
  has_many :infos, through: :child
  has_many :settings, through: infos
  has_many :subsettings, through: :settings
  ...
end
```

Then you should be able to call...

```
Parent.joins(:subsettings).where("parent.pname = ? OR subsetting.sname =?", x)
```

Two things to note about the `.where()` call:

1. Because you are querying against multiple joined tables, you need to preface the column with the table name.
2. The table name is singular, not plural. That's why `subsetting` and not `subsettings`.